# Authenticate users to SharePoint 2013 on premise from JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, authentication

I am trying to connect my mobile app to on premise SharePoint 2013 server. I have followed some of the blogs on authenticating using JavaScript but all of them are explaining to connect SharePoint online (Office 365).

I have tried one of the approach and I was getting below Error.

```
<psf:error>
<psf:value>0x80048820</psf:value>
<psf:internalerror>
<psf:code>0x80045c01</psf:code>
<psf:text>Invalid STS request.&#x000D;&#x000A;</psf:text>
</psf:internalerror>
</psf:error>
```

Envelope which I used is as below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
<a:Actions:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:UsernameToken>
<o:Username>' + emailAddress + '</o:Username>
<o:Password>' + password + '</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
<wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
<a:EndpointReference>
<a:Address>' + siteFullUrl + '</a:Address>
</a:EndpointReference>
</wsp:AppliesTo>
<t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
<t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
<t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
</t:RequestSecurityToken>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

$.ajax({
    url: "http://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf",
    data: env,
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (msg, textStatus, result) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var responseBody = $(result.responseText).find("S\\:Body");
        var requestSecurityTokenResponse = responseBody.find("wst\\:requestSecurityTokenResponse");
        var lifeTime = requestSecurityTokenResponse.find("wst\\:LifeTime");
        var expiresAt = lifeTime.find("wsu\\:Expires").text();

        token = $(result.responseText).find("wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken").text();

        alert(result.responseText);

        getFedAuthCookies();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown + 'error login:' + jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

    }
});
```

Is there any SRF (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf`) link for SharePoint 2013 on premise.

How can I authenticate users using JavaScript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Rahul, did you find the solution? we also have a same issue.

Comment: @PS No I didn't found anything yet.

Comment: Hi did you found any solution on these

Comment: @Subha Hi Subha, No I am still not able to find any solution on this.

Comment: This doesn't and will not work for on premise sharepoints

Comment: For on premise SharePoints follow this post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179057/attempted-folder-creation-results-in-403-forbidden

Answer (score 1):

If your password has special characters it can interfere with XML syntax, please try only alphanumeric password or escape your password.