# Attempted Folder Creation Results in (403) Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I cannot see why I am getting a 403 error on this code to add a folder to Documents library of a SharePoint Online site.

```
public static JToken AddFolder_SO(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials, Options options)
{

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {

        client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");

        // Get Digest
        var digestUrl = new Uri(webUri, "/_api/contextinfo");
        var digestResult = client.UploadString(digestUrl, "POST");
        var dr = JToken.Parse(digestResult);
        var digest = dr["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();

        // So far so good! FormDigest is returned here so I know I have correct credentials
        // Add Digest to next request
        client.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);

        var endpointUri = new Uri(webUri + "/_api/web/folders");
        string payloadString = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/Shared Documents/New Folder'}";

        // Fails here!!
        var result = client.UploadString(endpointUri, "POST", payloadString);
        var t = JToken.Parse(result);
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        return t["d"];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this error occurs since the request for acquiring form digest is always performed against *root site*:

```
var digestUrl = new Uri(webUri, "/_api/contextinfo");  //always returns root site
```

while the folder is getting created under *a different site collection*.

For example, lets say you `webUri` is set to `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/sites/news`, then the following query:

```
var digestUrl = new Uri(webUri, "/_api/contextinfo");  //<- relative url will be lost
var digestResult = client.UploadString(digestUrl, "POST");
```

will be executed for the following resource url: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo`

To avoid such kind of confusions, i would suggest to specify [`WebClient.BaseAddress Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.net.webclient.baseaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) that:

> Gets or sets the base URI for requests made by a WebClient.

In that case resources could be specified via *relative url*, for example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.BaseAddress = webUri.ToString();
     client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
     client.Credentials = credentials;
     client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json;odata=verbose");
     client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json;odata=verbose");

     // Get Digest
     var digestUrl = "_api/contextinfo"; //<- relative url
     var digestResult = client.UploadString(digestUrl, "POST");
     var dr = JToken.Parse(digestResult);
     var digest = dr["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();

     //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this hint. Before this I never considered that the root site and my library's site might use a different form digest.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly probably this is due to security violation with the mismatched X-RequestDigest. Following link may be useful [How form digest value header works in SharePoint](https://kushanlahiru.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/how-what-why-x-requestdigest-formdigestvalue-header-value-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you need to add the authorization to the header?

```
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", 
  "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

"You do not need the access token if you make this call from inside an add-in web, as you would in a SharePoint-hosted add-in. Note that you cannot obtain an access token from code that is running on a browser client. You must obtain the access token from code that is running on a server."

[Reference MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

Comment: This is a simple console application that this is running in.  I am getting the credentials using new SharePointOnlineCredentials(options.UserName, passWord);.  Is the accessToken in the SharePointOnlineCredentials object somewhere?

Comment: Take a look at the following MSDN article:
Handle security tokens in provider-hosted low-trust SharePoint Add-ins
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn762763.aspx